# SpringBoot Cache を拡張し、ビジネスロジックを追加したい。

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java8, redis

SpringBoot Cacheの実現案を検討している。キャッシュプロバイダーはRedisになる。
@Cacheableには、key:valueでメソッドの結果をキャッシュする。
業務要件としては、結果をキャッシュすることだけではなく、keyをhsetに保存する必要がある。
そのため、結果をキャッシュした後に、ビジネスロジックを実行させる手段があるか？
調べたところ、CacheResolverではなさそうだ。ソースは以下になる。

```
    @Caching(
            cacheable={@Cacheable(value ="hello", key="#myUser.name + #root.methodName") },
            put={@CachePut(value="hello", key="#myUser.name + #root.methodName", condition="#myUser.age==12") },
            evict={@CacheEvict(value="hello", key="#myUser.name + #root.methodName", allEntries=false, condition="#myUser.age==99")}
    )
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getResultList(MyUser myUser) {
        Map<String, Object> resultMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap1.put("result", "result10");
        Map<String, Object> resultMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap2.put("result", "result20");
        System.out.println("MyRedisService.getResultList executed! input : " + myUser.toString());
        return List.of(resultMap1, resultMap2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

一つ方法を見つけました。

Step１：RedisCacheを拡張する。`get` メソッドをオーバーライドし、ビジネスロジックを追加する。
Step２：RedisCacheManagerを拡張する。`createRedisCache` メソッドをオーバーライドし、Step1に拡張したRedisCacheを利用する。
Step３：Step２にて拡張したRedisCacheManagerをコンフィグレーションクラスにBeanとして作成する。